# Posting a message and uploading a picture

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I have a webform in asp.net and I am using the facebook c# sdk.
After filling the form, is it possible to post a message on the user's wall and upload a picture (generated by the application) in the album at the same time? (just clicking a button)

Than you. :)

I think now is clear. ^_^